# Understanding MCPL function call

Tags: mcpl

Analyzing a solution to [the eight queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) using bitwise operations written by [Martin Richards](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/users/mr/), I'm having a hard time understanding basic MCPL function syntax, despite consulting [the language manual](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mr10/mcplman.pdf).
Given below is the full program:

```
GET "mcpl.h"

STATIC count, all

FUN try
: ?,  =all,  ? => count++
: ld, cols, rd => LET poss = ~(ld | cols | rd) & all
                  WHILE poss DO
                  { LET bit = poss & -poss
                    poss -:= bit
                    try( (ld|bit)<<1, cols|bit, (rd|bit)>>1 )
                  }

FUN start : =>
  all := 1
  FOR n = 1 TO 12 DO
  { count := 0
    try(0, 0, 0)
    writef("There are %5d solutions to %2d-queens problem\n", count, n)
    all := 2*all + 1
  }
  RETURN 0
```

What I fail to understand is the first two lines of the function `try`, namely, the question mark `?` syntax and how parameters are passed (and handled).

The manual reads that

> A question mark (?) may be used as a constant with undefined value.

as well as

> Patterns are used in function definitions. *[...]* A question mark (?) or empty pattern will match any argument value.

What does this syntax mean for the parameters and how are `ld`, `cols` and `rd` given their initial values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding a paper that further discusses the above and other similar algorithms, I came to find that

```
: ?, =all,  ? => count++
```

essentially checks if `cols == all` and if so, a complete solution has been found (increase `count`).
`ld`, `cols` and `rd` are given parameter values.
What still looks odd to me is the check being executed before the parameters are used, so I might still be missing some details.